# KeyError when applying with_columns iteratively over different columns when using pl.struct on Polars LazyFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars, keyerror, lazyframe

I have the following issue with Polars's LazyFrame "Structs" (pl.struct) and "apply" (a.k.a. map_elements) in with_columns

The idea here is trying to apply a custom logic to a group of values that belong to more than one column

I have been able to achieve this using DataFrames; however, when switching to LazyFrames, a KeyError is raised whenever I try to access a column in the dictionary sent by the struct to the function. I'm looping through columns, one by one, in order to apply different functions (mapped elsewhere to their names, but in the examples below I'll just use the same one for simplicity)

- Working DataFrame implementation

```
my_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
        "bar": ["w", "x", "y", "z"], 
        "notes": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    }
)

print(my_df)

cols_to_validate = ("foo", "bar")

def validate_stuff(value, notes):
    # Any custom logic
    if value not in ["a", "b", "x"]:
        return f"FAILED {value} - PREVIOUS ({notes})"
    else:
        return notes

for col in cols_to_validate:
    my_df = my_df.with_columns(
        pl.struct([col, "notes"]).map_elements(
            lambda row: validate_stuff(row[col], row["notes"])
        ).alias("notes")
    )

print(my_df)
```

- Broken LazyFrame implementation

```
my_lf = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": ["a", "b", "c", "d"], 
        "bar": ["w", "x", "y", "z"], 
        "notes": ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    }
).lazy()

def validate_stuff(value, notes):
    # Any custom logic
    if value not in ["a", "b", "x"]:
        return f"FAILED {value} - PREVIOUS ({notes})"
    else:
        return notes

cols_to_validate = ("foo", "bar")

for col in cols_to_validate:
    my_lf = my_lf.with_columns(
        pl.struct([col, "notes"]).map_elements(
            lambda row: validate_stuff(row[col], row["notes"])
        ).alias("notes")
    )

print(my_lf.collect())
```

(Ah, yeah, do notice that individually executing each iteration does work, so it's not making any sense to me why the for loop breaks)

```
my_lf = my_lf.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["foo", "notes"]).map_elements(
        lambda row: validate_stuff(row["foo"], row["notes"])
    ).alias("notes")
)

my_lf = my_lf.with_columns(
    pl.struct(["bar", "notes"]).map_elements(
        lambda row: validate_stuff(row["bar"], row["notes"])
    ).alias("notes")
)
```

I have found a workaround using pl.col instead to achieve my desired result, but I would like to know whether Structs can be used the same way with LazyFrames right as I did with DataFrames, or it's actually a bug in this Polars version

I'm using Polars 0.19.13, BTW. Thank you for your attention

Comment: “do notice that individually executing each iteration does work” — it doesn't work; it fails when you run `my_lf.collect()`

Comment: @BallpointBen It actually does for me. After running each step and printing the collected DF, it prints the result without any errors https://imgur.com/a/0mSiokU . What error did you get? The same KeyError?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/JakobGM/patito) project seems to overlap with what you're trying to do.

Comment: This has come up a few times previously (e.g. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12057) - it seems like something could be added to the docs/userguide somewhere as it can be somewhat confusing.

Comment: @J.Alvarez I must have accidentally chained some stuff that I shouldn't have. You're right, it does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more of a general "gotcha" with Python itself: [Official Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result)

It breaks because `col` ends up with the same value for every `lambda`

One approach is to use a named/keyword arg:

```py
lambda row, col=col: validate_stuff(row[col], row["notes"])
```

```py
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ notes                             │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---                               │
│ str ┆ str ┆ str                               │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ w   ┆ FAILED w - PREVIOUS (1)           │
│ b   ┆ x   ┆ 2                                 │
│ c   ┆ y   ┆ FAILED y - PREVIOUS (FAILED c - … │
│ d   ┆ z   ┆ FAILED z - PREVIOUS (FAILED d - … │
└─────┴─────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative approach

Instead of using `map_elements` try monkey patching an expression based custom function like this:

```
pl.Expr.validation = lambda col: (
    pl.concat_list(
        pl.when(~col.is_in(['a','b','c']))
        .then(pl.lit("failed ") + col)
    )
    .list.drop_nulls()
    .list.join(' ')
)
```

This uses when/then to see if the value of the column is in ['a','b','c'], if it's not then it returns "failed " and then the column value. It wraps all instances of that in a list, it drops the nulls (anytime col is in ['a','b','c'] it produces a null), then it `join`s all the elements of the list into a single string.

With that function defined and patched to the `pl.Expr` namespace you can now just do...

```
my_df.with_columns(notes=pl.col('foo','bar').validation())
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────┬─────┬───────────────────┐
│ foo ┆ bar ┆ notes             │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---               │
│ str ┆ str ┆ str               │
╞═════╪═════╪═══════════════════╡
│ a   ┆ w   ┆ failed w          │
│ b   ┆ x   ┆ failed x          │
│ c   ┆ y   ┆ failed y          │
│ d   ┆ z   ┆ failed d failed z │
└─────┴─────┴───────────────────┘
```